# Drop down links not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website that has a horizontal menu bar with a drop down sub-menu that appears when hovering over the parent menu item.  The links to the sub menu works in a regular browser, however, when using my iPhone, the links to the sub menu do not work.  It previously worked only in a long press mode, but I didn't want the long press mode so I added the following code in my CSS to remove the long press mode:

```
.navWrap .top-bar2 li.menu-item {
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none!important;
}
```

and I also added the following javascript (because the CSS didn't work and some people suggested the javascript solution):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";</script>
```

You can test this by going to the following link:  http://sa4iserver1.com/~hoffer/  -- at this time, the only menu item that has a drop down sub-menu is the **RENT** menu item.

Any suggestions on how to make the sub-menu links clickable via iPhone/iPad would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post some code or we cannot help, we don't want to use the inspect element tool... Also, keep it short and consistent, only the navigation bar, please.

Comment: For mobile devices, clicking on parent menu item that has a sub menu will open/display the sub menu, however, clicking on the sub menu item doesn't open its intended page.